# publish a file and a decryption key to jms queue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms

I have a requirement to publish an encrypted file (file size can be    upto 100 M.B) to a jms queue.  Along with the file i have    to  send a    decryption key to the same message which is used by the    jms listener to to decrypt file.

I have attached the applicationContext.xml and the jms publisher.    Currently i am tryign to use MapMessage to  publish    both the file and    the key, but getting the below error.

```
2015-12-09 19:31:12,709  INFO [simBatchQueueListener-1] - Received a message for updating organization
2015-12-09 19:31:12,719 DEBUG [simBatchQueueListener-1] - Received a JMS message: Key ->null
2015-12-09 19:31:12,729 DEBUG [simBatchQueueListener-1] - Received a JMS message: File ->null
2015-12-09 19:31:12,729 DEBUG [simBatchQueueListener-1] - Received a JMS message: bytesMessage ->null
weblogic.jms.common.MessageFormatException: [JMSClientExceptions:055130]Invalid data type: java.io.BufferedWriter
        at weblogic.jms.common.MapMessageImpl.setObject(MapMessageImpl.java:234)
        at com.vodafone.m2m.kssv.jms.JMSNotifier$1.createMessage(JMSNotifier.java:113)
        at com.vodafone.m2m.kssv.jms.JMSNotifier$1.createMessage(JMSNotifier.java:106)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:602)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$4.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:583)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:493)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:579)
        at com.vodafone.m2m.kssv.jms.JMSNotifier.publishMessage(JMSNotifier.java:106)
        at com.vodafone.m2m.kssv.directoryscanner.file.SIMBatchReturnFileProcessor.run(SIMBatchReturnFileProcessor.java:88)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The jms publish should be synchronous. Once the message is read from    the queue an ID will be created and the ID need to be acknowledged to    the publisher.

As I am new to coding jms could anyone please help me how I can    achieve this.

public class JMSNotifier {

```
private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JMSNotifier.class);
private static final String myName = JMSNotifier.class.getSimpleName();
private String filename = null;
private FileInputStream inStream = null;
private BytesMessage bytesMessage = null;
private int bytes_read = 0;
private int BUFLEN = 64;
private byte[] buf1 = new byte[BUFLEN];
private byte[] buf2 = new byte[BUFLEN];
private int length = 0;
private int exitResult = 0;
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
private String simBatchQueue;
private MapMessage  m = null;

@Required
public void setSimBatchQueue(String simBatchQueue) {
    this.simBatchQueue = simBatchQueue;
}

public synchronized void publishMessage(String destinationName, String msg) throws JMSException {
    LOG.debug("Sending message {} on {} queue...", msg.toString(), destinationName);

    try {
        filename = new String("C:\\Vijay\\cleartext.txt");
        inStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Problem getting file: " + e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    if (Constants.SIM_BATCH_QUEUE.equals(destinationName)) {
        destinationName = simBatchQueue;
        LOG.trace("{}: Attempting messgage for D_N_SIM_BATCH_QUEUE {} ", myName, simBatchQueue);
    } else {
        LOG.trace("{}: Unknow JMS destinaion name {} ", myName, destinationName);
        throw new JMSException("Unknow JMS destinaion name {}" + destinationName);
    }

    jmsTemplate.send(destinationName, new MessageCreator() {

        @Override
        public MapMessage createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
            try {

                m = session.createMapMessage();
                m.setObject("file", writeToFile(inStream));
                m.setObject("key","123");
                return m;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return m;
            }
        }
    });
}

public static String prepareNormalDateString() {

    Calendar tzCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhhmmss");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    StringBuffer date = new StringBuffer(dateFormat.format(tzCal.getTime()));
    date.append("UTC");

    return (date.toString());
}
private BufferedWriter writeToFile(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String time = prepareNormalDateString();
    String filepath = "C:\\vijay\\File" + time + ".csv";
    String line;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    try {
         bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filepath));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            bufferedWriter.write(line);
        }
        bufferedWriter.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return bufferedWriter;

}
```

}

public class SimBatchQueueMessageHandler implements MessageListener {

```
private static org.slf4j.Logger myLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimBatchQueueMessageHandler.class);
private String myName = SimBatchQueueMessageHandler.class.getSimpleName();
int bytes_read = 0;
final int BUFLEN = 64;
byte[] buf1 = new byte[BUFLEN];
byte[] buf2 = new byte[BUFLEN];
int length = 0;
int exitResult = 0;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
File newFile = null;
private static int count = 1;

@Override
public synchronized void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {
        myLogger.info("Received a message for updating organization");
        Source source;
        count = count + 1;
        if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
            source = new StringSource(textMessage.getText());
            myLogger.debug("Text Message received {}", textMessage.getText());
        } else if (message instanceof MapMessage) {
            MapMessage msg = (MapMessage) message;
            myLogger.debug("Received a JMS message: Key ->" + msg.getObject("key"));
            myLogger.debug("Received a JMS message: File ->" + msg.getObject("file"));
            Object bytesMessage =  msg.getObject("file");
             myLogger.debug("Received a JMS message: bytesMessage ->" + bytesMessage);
        } else if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
        else {
            throw new MessageConversionException("Unsupported JMS Message type " + message.getClass() + ", expected instance of TextMessage or BytesMessage for " + message);
        }

        Object[] params = new Object[]{myName};

    } catch (JMSException jmsEx) {
        myLogger.error("Error occured while publishing" + jmsEx);
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd 
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core  
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd  
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet 
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

    <!--
            Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes:
            Spring's @Required and @Autowired, as well as JSR 250's @Resource.
    -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>file:///${MYCOMPONENT_CONFIG_PATH}/log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>file:///${MYCOMPONENT_CONFIG_PATH}/jdbc.properties</value>
                <!--<value>file:///${MYCOMPONENT_CONFIG_PATH}/MYCOMPONENTConfig.xml</value>-->
                <value>file:///${MYCOMPONENT_CONFIG_PATH}/MYCOMPONENT.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--
            Uses Apache Commons DBCP for connection pooling. See Commons DBCP documentation
            for the required JAR files. Alternatively you can use another connection pool
            such as C3P0, similarly configured using Spring.
    -->

    <!-- USE FOR GLASSFISH DATABASE POOLING    
         <bean id="dataSourceMYCOMPONENT" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="${MYCOMPONENT.jdbc.dataSource}"/>
        </bean>-->


    <!-- USE FOR SPRING DATABASE POOLING -->

    <bean id="dataSourceMYCOMPONENT" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
          p:password="${jdbc.password}" >
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="2"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="500"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value ="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value ="1800000"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value ="300000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="nativeJdbcExtractor"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dao" class="com.mycompany.m2m.MYCOMPONENT.support.dataaccess.jdbc.JdbcDataAccessObject">
        <!-- Must set schemaName before dataSource! -->
        <property name="schemaName" value="${jdbc.schema}"/>
        <property name="dbUser" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceMYCOMPONENT"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Ends -->


    <!-- USE FOR JMS CONFIGURATION ************************* -->
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="${MYCOMPONENT.jms.connectionFactory}" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">${MYCOMPONENT.jndi.initialFactory}</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${MYCOMPONENT.jndi.providerUrl}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="cache" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="simBatchQueue" />
        <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="sessionAcknowledgeModeName" value="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE" />
        <property name="sessionTransacted" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsNotifier" class="com.mycompany.m2m.MYCOMPONENT.jms.JMSNotifier">
        <property name="simBatchQueue" value="${MYCOMPONENT.jms.simBatchQueue}" />
    </bean>

      <!-- JMS Message Listener  to handle messages from MYCOMPONENT-->
    <bean id="simBatchQueueMessageListener" class="com.mycompany.m2m.MYCOMPONENT.jms.listener.SimBatchQueueMessageHandler"/>

    <bean id="simBatchQueue" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate" ref="jndiTemplate" />
        <property name="jndiName" value="${MYCOMPONENT.jms.simBatchQueue}" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="simBatchQueueListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destination" ref="simBatchQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="simBatchQueueMessageListener" />
        <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true"/>
        <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="false"/>
        <!--<property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="${sasm.jms.orgDurableSubName}"/>-->
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: Since it's impossible to "*attach*" any files here, add ([edit]) all relevant code to your question.